# Move files after changing theirs names, how?

Tags: excel, vba

I´ve modified a code in a way that it rename my file names based in a column. However, there´s a loop and the program is changing the name of the same file until gets an error. How can I change the name, move the file to another folder and then process the next file? Below is the code and the important part is separated by "--------------

Thanks!

```
Option Explicit

Sub ListFiles()

'http://www.xl-central.com/list-the-files-in-a-folder-and-subfolders.html

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Set a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime by using
'Tools > References in the Visual Basic Editor (Alt+F11)

'Declare the variables
Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim objTopFolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim strTopFolderName As String

'Insert the headers for Columns A through F
Range("A1").Value = "File Name"
Range("B1").Value = "File Size"
Range("C1").Value = "File Type"
Range("D1").Value = "Date Created"
Range("E1").Value = "Date Last Accessed"
Range("F1").Value = "Date Last Modified"
Range("G1").Value = "Parent Folder"
Range("H1").Value = "Short Path"
Range("K1").Value = "New Name"

'Assign the top folder to a variable
strTopFolderName = "D:\"

'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Get the top folder
Set objTopFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strTopFolderName)

'Call the RecursiveFolder routine
Call RecursiveFolder(objTopFolder, True)

'Change the width of the columns to achieve the best fit
Columns.AutoFit


End Sub

Sub RecursiveFolder(objFolder As Scripting.Folder, _
IncludeSubFolders As Boolean)


'Declare the variables
Dim objFile As Scripting.File
Dim objSubFolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim NextRow As Long
Dim Sample As String

'Find the next available row
NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

'Loop through each file in the folder
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    Cells(NextRow, "A").Value = objFile.Name
    Cells(NextRow, "B").Value = objFile.Size
    Cells(NextRow, "C").Value = objFile.Type
    Cells(NextRow, "D").Value = objFile.DateCreated
    Cells(NextRow, "E").Value = objFile.DateLastAccessed
    Cells(NextRow, "F").Value = objFile.DateLastModified
    Cells(NextRow, "G").Value = objFile.ParentFolder
    Cells(NextRow, "H").Value = objFile.ShortPath

  '-----------------------------
    'Comandos para copiar e colar as fórmulas que definirão o novo nome do arquivo
        Range("I1").Copy
            Range("I" & NextRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormulas)
            Range("I" & NextRow).Calculate
                Range("J1").Copy
                    Range("J" & NextRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormulas)
                    Range("J" & NextRow).Calculate

    Sample = Range("J" & NextRow).Value 'Nome da amostra

        objFile.Name = Sample & objFile.Name 'Mudança do nome do arquivo para incluir o nome da amostra

            Cells(NextRow, "K").Value = objFile.Name 'Inserção do novo nome do arquivo após alteração

  '----------------------------
    NextRow = NextRow + 1

Next objFile

'Loop through files in the subfolders
If IncludeSubFolders Then
    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        Call RecursiveFolder(objSubFolder, True)
    Next objSubFolder
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: all I can see is lots of code!

Comment: Sorry Mehow, I thought that would be important show all the code, but I've highlighted where the code has to be changed. Anyway, thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying the elements of a loop from inside that loop in a way that probably invalidates (or refreshes) the object whose elements you are iterating - in your case, the objFolder.Files collection.

Solution: in your loop, collect the old as well as the new names of the files in a collection (an array or whatever you like) instead of renaming the files directly. Then, iterate once more through your new collection (instead of objFolder.Files) and do the renaming.

Comment: Olaf, I´ve found some codes using objFSO.MoveFile. So, I've declared objFSO As New FileSystemObject and after renaming the file, I've used the new file path (complete path) to move it. I´m going to post these changes below. What do you think? It was an efficient solution?

Comment: Cells(NextRow, "K").Value = objFile.Name _ 
                Cells(NextRow, "H").Value = objFile.Path _ 
                
                SamplePath = objFile.Path _ 
        
        objFSO.MoveFile SamplePath, "D:\NewFolder\"

Comment: It may be ok, but I am still not sure if it is future proof and optimal as moving the file still changes the object (objFolder.Files) through which you are iterating. Then again, if it works and if you can move the files inside your loop without problems, go for it. To be sure, I'd do a step by step debugging and check if the loop still does what you think it does.

Comment: Olaf, the code is working very well. If you want, a can send the finished version to you, as soon as possible, maybe it could be useful. Again, thank you so much for your attention.

Comment: Felipe, glad to hear it works. Thanks for your offer, but that won't be necessary. :-)